# ignore NaN in .diff() with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, diff, nan

I need to compute differences between elements along axis=1 for each row ignoring the missing values (NaN). For example:

```
       0     1     2     3     4     5
20   NaN   7.0   5.0   NaN   NaN   8.0
21   7.0   5.0   NaN   NaN   8.0   NaN
22   5.0   NaN   NaN   8.0   NaN   7.0
23   NaN   NaN   8.0   NaN   7.0   NaN
24   NaN   8.0   NaN   7.0   NaN  10.0
25   8.0   NaN   7.0   NaN  10.0   NaN
26   NaN   7.0   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN
27   7.0   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN   9.0
28   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN   9.0   6.0
29  10.0   NaN   NaN   9.0   6.0   6.0
```

so, ideally I need to get :

```
 7.0   5.0   8.0
 7.0   5.0   8.0
 5.0   8.0   7.0
       8.0   7.0
 8.0   7.0  10.0
```

then I can apply standard .diff(axis=1) and get what I need. However, I'm struggling to extract non NaN values from each row. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use a filter with the condition `item == item`?  `NaN` will fail a comparison to itself.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Prune, can you explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use `np.argsort` on the truth values of null-ness with `mergesort` to ensure I preserve the order of non-nulls.

```
v = df.values
a = (~np.isnan(v)).argsort(1, kind='mergesort')
b = v[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None], a]

b

[[ nan  nan  nan   7.   5.   8.]
 [ nan  nan  nan   7.   5.   8.]
 [ nan  nan  nan   5.   8.   7.]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan   8.   7.]
 [ nan  nan  nan   8.   7.  10.]
 [ nan  nan  nan   8.   7.  10.]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan   7.  10.]
 [ nan  nan  nan   7.  10.   9.]
 [ nan  nan  nan  10.   9.   6.]
 [ nan  nan  10.   9.   6.   6.]]
```

I'll then drop columns with all nulls and place back into a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(b[:, ~np.isnan(b).all(0)], df.index)

       0     1     2     3
20   NaN   7.0   5.0   8.0
21   NaN   7.0   5.0   8.0
22   NaN   5.0   8.0   7.0
23   NaN   NaN   8.0   7.0
24   NaN   8.0   7.0  10.0
25   NaN   8.0   7.0  10.0
26   NaN   NaN   7.0  10.0
27   NaN   7.0  10.0   9.0
28   NaN  10.0   9.0   6.0
29  10.0   9.0   6.0   6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you already know how to compute differences when all the values are filled in.  Use that process, but modify the comparison step.  Whatever you use to compare existing values, include a filter to accept only `item`s for which `item == item`.

By definition, `Nan` will fail *any* comparison operation.  `NaN == NaN` is `False`; `NaN != NaN` is also `False`.  If you include a condition that the time must be equal to itself, you filter out `Nan` and `Inf` entries.

Is that enough to let you continue?

Comment: I am bit confused, as I do not normally run comparison while differentiating. I understand what you mean, however, I can't see the step of filtering in my case.

Comment: Can you edit your posting with the code you'd use for "normally"?  This will help focus answers.